# Clearing up some tag confusion

Tags: discussion, tags

We've got a few tags tackling the theoretical basis of IOTA and the implementation of it that seem a bit messy. There are the following tags: *tangle*, *iota-network*, *dag*, *iri*, *full-node*, *api* and *white-paper*. Here we go. I'll include suggestions which I'll duplicate in answers to enable voting on each of the suggestions individually.

### Analysis

[tangle](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tangle) **vs.** [iota-network](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iota-network)

Unfortunately they seem to be quite strangely used. As I see it and what I wrote into the tag wiki of *iota-network* at the beginning of the year is that the tag should be used for questions covering the *productive* network of IOTA.

> Use this tag for questions that are about the IOTA network as a whole. This includes questions about the reliability, scaling and functionality of the network itself as an implemented version of the tangle based on full nodes running the IRI.
>
> [...]
>
> - Is the question about any aspect of the productive IOTA network?
> - Is the question NOT about understanding the tangle, test nets, generic node configuration or directed acyclic graphs?

That tag wiki edit was approved by two high reputation users.

My expectation would be that the tag *tangle* should only cover ***theoretical considerations*** of how the tangle works. Not however any questions about the running, well, IOTA network.

> Wiki "For questions about the tangle, the directed acyclic graph which has the same function in IOTA as the blockchain has in other cryptocurrencies."

Source: Tag excerpt

**Suggestions:**

1. Make a clear distinction between productive network and theoretical basis.
2. Decide for all double tagged questions which applies.
3. Look through both categories to make sure the questions are properly tagged.

---

**[tangle](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tangle) vs. [dag](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dag)**

The questions for *dag* are all over the place. It's from a taxonomy standpoint a hyperonym of *tangle* which is the specific directed acyclic graph IOTA uses.

**Suggestions:**

1. Decide if non-IOTA dag questions are even on-topic? If not, remove tag altogether.
2. Either way re-tag all IOTA specific questions with *tangle*.

---

[tangle](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tangle) **vs.** [white-paper](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/white-paper)

Those questions are not discussing white papers in general but the IOTA whitepaper. Currently the only remaining question tackles something discussed in the white paper.

> In this paper we analyze the mathematical foundations of IOTA, a cryptocurrency
>   for the Internet-of-Things (IoT) industry. The main feature of this
>   novel cryptocurrency is the tangle, a directed acyclic graph (DAG) for storing
>   transactions.

Source: [IOTA white paper, titled *"The Tangle"*](https://iota.org/IOTA_Whitepaper.pdf)

**Suggestions:**

1. Remove tag *white paper*
2. Tag theoretical discussions about the *content* of the white paper with *tangle*

---

[iri](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iri) **vs.** [full-node](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/full-node)

> For questions related to Iota Reference Implementation: the official Iota full node implementation.

Source: IRI tag excerpt

> Use this tag for Questions related to IOTA full-node:
>
> This is an IRI (IOTA Reference Implementation) running and being accessed locally via a GUI. Any full node needs to be connected to neighbours via a static IP in order to function. Learn how you can run a full node and how they help the IOTA ecosystem in our GUI tutorials!

Source: IRI tag excerpt + wiki

Those two seem more or less interchangeable *according to the descriptions*. There's also 11 questions tagged with both which is a quarter or a sixth, depending from which side you're looking.

**Suggestions:**

1. Create a new tag: [iri-node](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iri-node)
2. Have a moderator (soon<sup><sup><sub>TM</sub></sup></sup>) migrate all questions to that new tag.
3. Create tag synonyms for *iri* and *full-node* to point to *iri-node*
4. Write a proper tag wiki for that tag—it will have 90+ questions

---

[api](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/api)

**Suggestions:**

1. Rename it to *iri-api*
2. Create synonym from *api* to *iri-api*

---

<sub>P.S. I also killed the tags *replication*, *website*, *performance*, *system*, *utility*, *future*, *value* and *stolen*.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

## Use *"iota-network"* for productive network; *"tangle"* for theoretical questions

> 1. Make a clear distinction between productive network and theoretical basis.
> 2. Decide for all double tagged questions which applies.
> 3. Look through both categories to make sure the questions are properly tagged.

Answer (score 2):

## Create one tag *"IRI-node"* from *"IRI"* and *"full-node"*

> 1. Create a new tag: [iri-node](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iri-node)
> 2. Have a moderator (soon<sup><sup><sub>TM</sub></sup></sup>) migrate all questions to that new tag.
> 3. Create tag synonyms for *iri* and *full-node* to point to *iri-node*
> 4. Write a proper tag wiki for that tag—it will have 90+ questions

[status-completed](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Answer (score 1):

## Rename tag *"API"* to *"IRI-API"*

> 1. Rename it to *iri-api*
> 2. Create synonym from *api* to *iri-api*

[status-completed](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Comment: Not sure what the reason/benefits are here. Do you think people could confuse the IRI API with other APIs?

Comment: There might be other apis that are on-topic later on; a specific node api for example

Answer (score 0):

## Rename tag *"IRI"*

> 1. Rename it to *iri-api*
> 2. Create synonym from *api* to *iri-api*

It's the other half of naming the node questions iri-node. With both iri-node and iri-api they are clearly distinct and everyone who tags a question and types in "iri" will get two suggestions iri-api and iri-node and will hopefully pick the right one.

[status-completed](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Comment: I don't see why iri should refer to the API and not to the node implementation (IRI is an Acronym for IOTA Reference Implementation)

Comment: @mihi It's the other half of naming the node questions *iri-node*. With both [tag:iri-node] and [tag:iri-api] they are clearly distinct and everyone who tags a question and types in "iri" will get two suggestions iri-api and iri-node and will hopefully pick the right one.

Comment: I cannot change my vote when only a comment was added? Did not notice that before :-(

Comment: @mihi now after an edit it should be possible

Answer (score 0):

## non-IOTA questions are off-topic!

> 1. Decide if non-IOTA dag questions are even on-topic? If not, remove tag altogether.
> 2. Either way re-tag all IOTA specific questions with *tangle*.